# Weird outputs in Java?

Tags: java, accounting

I'm trying to make a basic command-line accounting application in Java and this is what I have come up with so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Accounting {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    while(true){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userinput = input.nextLine();

        String[] parts = userinput.split(" ");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String part3 = parts[2];

        int a = Integer.parseInt(part1);
        float r = Float.parseFloat(part2);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(part3);
        int Total = (int) Math.pow(a + ( 1 + ( r / 100 )), t);
        System.out.println(Total);
```

You put in 3 inputs amount, rate, and time. I was told the formula is `Total = a(1+(r/100))^t`. Whenever i put an input like 25000 6.9 15 i get a number over 2 billion (2147483647) Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're looking at an overflow, try using a `BigInteger` and its methods instead (and your formula is wrongly implemented).

Comment: `Math.pow(a + ( 1 + ( r / 100 )), t)` is not the same as "Total = a(1+(r/100))^t". The correct (second) equation raises a value between 1 and 2 to `t`; the incorrect first one raises (in the case of your example) 25000 to 15.

Comment: You are getting the results as defined in your calculation.  So either your input values are wrong, or your calculation is wrong.  What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: what your clde is actually doing is `Total = (a(1+(r/100)))^t`

Comment: Actually, it's `(a+1+r/100)^t`.

Comment: Pleace accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
double total = a*Math.pow(1.0+(r/100.0), t);
```

Comment: Downvoting  an answer without a proper explanation as long as the answer is apparently correct doesn't make any sense at all. However to the poster +1

Comment: Very kind of you, Sage.  I don't much care - I'm satisfied with my rep.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow(a + ( 1 + ( r / 100 )), t)` is not the same as "Total = a(1+(r/100))^t". The correct (second) equation raises a value between 1 and 2 to t; the incorrect first one raises (in the case of your example) 25000 to 15.

Comment: it seems you are the one who got the nail first as is evident from your comment +1 :)